# What is the difference between the FacebookWebMVC the Facebook NuGet packages?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

What's the difference between these two packages?

[image]

and

[image]

Now before everyone jumps in and says: One is for the `ASP.NET MVC` framework website(s) and the other is not, I'm under the impression that the `WebMvc` is a wrapper for the `MVC` framework.

As such, we don't need to write as much code.

So .. can someone please explain the difference with code.

eg. With the `Core` dll, u would have to write these 10 lines. With the `WebMvc` dll you can just use this `Action Method Attribute` or whatever...

Also, bonus points to any tutorials that explain how to use it, or some sample website code in codeplex, github, bitbucket, where-ever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FacebookWebMvc` depends on the `FacebookWeb` NuGet so when you install it it also installs the base package:

[image]

It contains helper functions adapted for ASP.NET MVC but they all use the core library.

Comment: Yeah .. but can u please give some code samples how we use that?

Comment: @Pure.Krome, what exactly are you interested in? The documentation contains many examples and getting started tutorials: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: hmm. i was there today/last night and they don't have examples there of MVC dll .. which was why i asked. just the core dll.

Comment: Here is an exact code what the documentation says. - "Make sure to download the source code and check "Samples" folder for working samples."
and there are MVC samples too. 
and FacebookWebMvc is dependent on FacebookWeb which is also dependent also on Facebook